# Why can't I dynamically create context providers in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

This is my attempt in accomplishing this and I can't seem to make it work:

```js
import React from 'react'

/**
 * Example of input:
 * [
 *  {
 *    Context: React.createContext(),
 *    value: { test: "hello" }
 *  },
 *  {
 *    Context: React.createContext(),
 *    value: { test: "world" }
 *  }
 * ]
 */

const recursive = (contexts, children) => {
    if(contexts.length < 1) return children;
    const { Context, value } = contexts[0];
    
    return (
        <Context.provider value={ value }>
            { recursive(contexts.shift()) }
        </Context.provider>
    )
}

function Contexts({ contexts, children }) {

    return (    
        <>
        { recursive(contexts, children) }
        </>
    )
}

export default Contexts;
```

Is this even possible to do and if so how, can I make it happen?

The reason why I'm using a recursive function is because there are children components that needs to live inside the contexts providers.

Comment: One problem is definitely the fact that you are changing props directly. You should `slice` before `shift`

Answer (score 0):

I am note sure whether this will be the only error, but your usage of `shift` is incorrect.

`shift` modifies the array in place and returns the removed object. That means that

```
{ recursive(contexts.shift()) }
```

will pass `contexts[0]` (the removed element) to the recursive call and it will also change the `context` array passed from `props`. Changing `props` is always a dangerous error.

To properly pass values to the next calls, you have to create an array copy:

```
const copy = contexts.slice();
copy.shift();

...
{ copy }
```

However, there is an easier way to write it:

```
if (contexts.length === 0) {
  return children;
}

const [{ Context, value }, ...otherContexts] = contexts;

return (
    <Context.provider value={value}>
        {otherContexts}
    </Context.provider>
)
```